# How to split text string in R based on capitalization?

Tags: regex, r, string, split

This is one the first string split occasions that I'm not sure can be accomplished in R.

I have a list of strings containing information in the form:

```
data <- c("Los Angeles DodgersAtlanta Braves",
        "Milwaukee BrewersChicago Cubs",
        "Arizona DiamondbacksMiami Marlins")
```

How would I go about splitting the two adjoining team names in each string?
Is there a way to find or split based on the capitalization of a string?

(Maybe a way to find when two lowercase characters precede a capital and split there? )

Comment: Did you try `(?<=[a-z]{2})(?=[A-Z])`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte where is 2 lowercase character precede

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you nailed it, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split with the following regex:

```
(?:\s|(?<=[a-z]))(?=[A-Z])
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT7iI9/1).

Comment: where is 2 lowercase character precede a capital?

Comment: Just a note:  In R you'd need to escape `\s` with an extra backslash, and denote `perl = TRUE`.  So something like `strsplit(data, "(?:\\s|(?<=[a-z]))(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: DodgersAtlanta  <-- rs precedes A

Comment: Thank you Richard, I was just about to ask about that

Comment: Would there be a way to keep the full team name together rather than splitting up the whole string into individual pieces? Right now I don't know of rule to rebuild the team names appropriately as the number of string fragments per team varies.  This problem was my reasoning behind trying to use the 2 lowercase characters preceding the capital as the split point. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @DerekPierson You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314875/how-to-split-text-string-in-r-based-on-capitalization/25314919?noredirect=1#comment39459182_25314875).

Comment: Great! Works as desired. Thank you all!